# Java random number with high probability

Tags: java, random, numbers

I have an array `char[] Select =  {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'}` and each element in this array has different probability to be selected. For example,

```
int[] Weight =  {10,30,25,60,20,70,10,80,20,30};
```

My requirement is to select 5 elements from this array and the element with high weight values has higher probability to be selected and these 5 elements should be different.

My plan is first sum the weight

```
int[] weightSum = {10, 40, 65, 125, 145, 215, 225, 305, 325, 355}
```

Then I use Random to generate a random number `k` in the range of [0,355]. Then looking for the first element which is bigger than `k` in the `weightSum[]`. This process are repeated 5 times.

The problem is that the element with high probability could be selected multiple times. I try to remove the duplicate elements at each iteration. The duplicates are removed, but element with high weight values are not selected.

How to solve this problem?

thanks.

Comment: shouldn't you look for the *last* element *smaller* than `k`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't maintain the cumulative sum or adjust it each time: (requires O(n) for each selection though)

```
char[] Select = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'};
int[] Weight = {10,30,25,60,20,70,10,80,20,30};
int sum = 355;
for(int a=0;i<5;i++){
    int rand = (int)(Math.random()*sum);
    int s=0;//temp cumulative sum
    int i=0;
    while( (s+=Weight[i])<rand)i++;
    result.add(Select[i]);

    sum-=Weight[i];//total weight is lower now
    Weight[i]=0;//if weight is 0 it will never be selected

}
```

edit: fixed so I don't subtract 0 from `sum`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand correctly, but how about something like this:

- after first selection you remove the selected element from  `char[] Select`
- you also remove the corresponding weight from `int[] Weight`
- regenerate `int[] weightSum`
- repeat the whole process

Comment: If s77 does not want repeats, the simplest thing would be after selecting a value set the corresponding weight to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I guess each time you remove the duplicates, you must also update your weightSum array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understanding your problem, but your algorithm sounds right: you should be doing something like storing each generated value in a list (based on random number generator), but first check to see if that number already exists in the list before adding it. Repeat until the list has 5 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

My statistics memory is a bit fuzzy, but I think what you want to do is remove the element from consideration after it's been selected.  In other words, after selecting the entry, remove that entry from `weightSum` and subtract its `Weight` from all subsequent entries and the range of the random number.  Might be easier to manage if you work with `ArrayList`s instead of primitive arrays.